# Differential equation $2f'(t)+tf(t)=0$ with $f(0)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation: $$2f'(t)+tf(t)=0$$ with $f(0)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

I tried to write $2f'(t)+tf(t)=0$ something like $(f(t)g(t))'=0$ for some function $g$ but it was unsuccesful.

I am not very good familiar with DE and can anyone show me how to solve it easily?

Comment: Hint: Notice that $\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} = \frac{d}{dt} \ln(f(t))$

Comment: Multiply $e^{t^2/4}$ on both sides.

Comment: @choco_addicted, Thanks a lot for nice hint! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, given $f'(t)+p(t)f(t)=q(t)$, multiply $\mu(t)=\exp\left(\int p(t)dt\right)$ on both sides. Since $\mu'(t)=p(t)\mu(t)$, you can use product rule to complete your purpose. In the problem, $p(t)=\frac{t}{2}$ and so $\mu(t)=e^{t^2/4+C}$. $C$ is an indeterminate constant, but I usually let $C=0$.

But separation of variables may be more useful when $q(t)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $2\frac{df}{dt}+tf=0\Rightarrow 2\frac{df}{f}=-tdt$ and integrate

Comment: Why we can write our equation in such form and divide to $f$?

Comment: The method is called separation of variables in ordinary differential equations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Answer (score 1):

$$2f'(t)+tf(t)=0$$
$$2\frac{df}{dt}+tf=0$$
$$\int{2\frac{df}{f}}=\int{-t}dt$$
$$2\ln(|f|)=-\frac{t^2}{2}+c$$
$$f(0)=\sqrt{\pi}$$
Thus,

$$c=2\ln(\sqrt{\pi})$$
$$2\ln(|f|)=-\frac{t^2}{2}+2\ln(\sqrt{\pi})$$
$$\ln(\frac{|f|}{\sqrt{\pi}})=\frac{-t^2}{4}$$